# why isn't this variable in a find iteration changing its value

Tags: bash, sed, find

I was trying to rename all files using `find` but after i ran this...

```
find . -name '*tablet*' -exec sh -c "new=$(echo {} | sed 's/tablet/mobile/') && mv {} $new" \;
```

i found that my files where gone, changed it to `echo` the value of $new and found that it always kept the name of the first file so it basically renamed all files to have the same name

```
$ find . -name '*tablet*' -exec sh -c "new=$(echo {} | sed 's/tablet/mobile/') && echo $new" \;
_prev_page.tablet.erb
_prev_page.tablet.erb
_prev_page.tablet.erb
_prev_page.tablet.erb
_prev_page.tablet.erb
_prev_page.tablet.erb
_prev_page.tablet.erb
```

also tried to change to `export new=...`, same result

Why doesn't the value of `new` change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem I believe is that the command substitution is expanded by bash once then find uses the result in each invocation. I could be wrong with the reason.

When I have similar stuff before I write out a shell script eg

```
#! /bin/bash
old="$1"
new="${1/tablet/mobile}"
if [[ "${old}" != "${new}" ]]; then
    mv "${old}" "${new}"
fi
```

that takes care of renaming the file then I can call that script from the find command

```
find . -name "*tablet*" -exec /path/to/script '{}' \;
```

makes things much simpler to sort out.

EDIT:

HAHA after some messing around with the quoting you can sort this out by changing the double quotes to single quotes encapsulating the command. As is the $() is expanded by the shell command. if done as below the command substitution is done by the shell invoked by the exec.

```
find . -name "*tablet*" -exec sh -c 'new=$( echo {} | sed "s/tablet/mobile/" ) && mv {} $new' \;
```

SO the issue is to do with when the command substitution is expanded, by puting it in single quotes we force the expansion in each invokation of sh.

Comment: ended up with something like that, but was curious as to why that didn't work, your answer makes sense, i'll wait a bit to see if someone else has something else to add.

Comment: After some experimenting got the answer. edited answer above.

Comment: oh bash, how i love you for these things lol, yea, that did it and now i get why, thanks :D